# Dependable Dropdown Menus without the use of Database (including an array)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I was working on an online shop website recently where I was to display products of different companies (like Nike, Puma etc). I needed dependable dropdown menus for it, so if for example someone select Nike option from the first dropdown, the second dropdown will populate only those items which are from Nike company not from others.
I made those menus by studying the free course [Dependable dropdown menus with jQuery and PHP](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/dependable-dropdown.html) by Sebastian Sulinski and this course worked very fine for my needs.

The project is already completed and submitted, but I want to learn about one thing. Sebastian Sulinski pull data from MySql database to put in the dropdown menus. Is there any way to pull the data from some file (which have array(s) of the items) included through PHP's include instead of pulling it from database (to make the process faster) and decrease load on database ?

Your Answer will be appreciated..

Thank You everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0):

of course,

Data held on the 'file system', in a database, or hardcoded in application code is still just 'data'.

Quite often in a web app there would be some static 'lists' available ( .xml or .json ) to populate static parts of a website.

Sure, if this data is not going to change, it makes sense in many ways to just serve it like you would images/css/javascript and save a round trip to the database.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit, how to accomplish it ?

Comment: how far have you got  ? Your question is *" Is there any way to pull the data from some file (which have array(s) of the items) included through PHP's ..."* - now you need to decide how you are storing the data ( likely .json or .xml ) - and try something. When you have and hit a proble give me a shout or post a new q **with the code** - cheers